# Arch Linux - No network available after crash

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

Wireless worked fine until VirtualBox make my laptop freeze. I had to unplug it. After reboot, when I use `wifi-menu`, no network is available. I have all my drivers, and all interfaces are `DOWN`. Whenever I try to turn one on, I have an error message :

```
"SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill"
```

Comment: What does `rfkill` show?

Comment: Command doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type

```
rfkill list
```

it will probably show that your wifi is blocked. Unblock it with

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

If `rfkill` is not installed on your system, you can install it with

```
sudo pacman -S rfkill
```

If you don't have internet access at all, you should still be able to do this by hand. See if you can find those files on your computer:

```
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/hard
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/soft
```

All they should contain is `0`, which means they are not blocked. If they contain `1`, change it to `0`. Maybe `rfkill0` is not your WiFi device, but e.g. Bluetooth. Then change `rfkill0` with `rfkill1` in the path's above.

I'm not sure if you have these path's on your system, since you haven't installed `rfkill`. I uninstalled `rfkill` and still had them, but of course that's no guarantee. In any way these are just softlinks and if they are not there, we have to find the files somewhere under `/sys/devices/`.

Comment: rfkill : Command doesn't exist.

Comment: @DelCrabman See my edited answer.

Comment: I somehow figured that I had to install the package, but since I don't have an ethernet cable, it will be tough...

Comment: @DelCrabman I see. See my edit again. Does that work for you?